# How to 3-color grid a 7 by 7 grid of squares

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I'am trying to figure out how to 3-color a 7 by 7 grid of squares that rotates but does not flip and I'm having a hard time getting started and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of some resources or help me get started with this problem.

Comment: What are you after? The total number of $3$-colourings? Can neighbouring squares have the same colour? Do you have to use all the colours?

Comment: Just the total number of colorings, there are not other restrictions.

Comment: Are you familiar with group theory?

Comment: I am not familiar

Comment: When rotating the square grid you will see that some squares must be the same color. In fact you can color the top left $3\times4$ grid any way you like, and then rotate that four times to color the entire grid (except the center). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes makes sense, I still have no idea how to start this problem though

Comment: I suggest the [Burnside lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). This requires the cycle index of the action of $C_4$ on the $49$ squares of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

We  use the  Burnside lemma,  which requires  the cycle  index of  the
action of $C_4$ on the $49$ squares. This is

$$Z(G) =
\frac{1}{4} (a_1^{49} + a_1 a_2^{24} + 2 a_1 a_4^{12}).$$

The first entry is the identity,  the second the $180$ degree rotation
and the third the two rotations by $90$ degrees and $270$ degrees.

This yields for colorings with at most $N$ colors:

$$A_N = \frac{1}{4} (N^{49} + N^{25} + 2 N^{13}).$$

For colorings with at most three colors this works out to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
59824832307866205347043.}$$

On the other hand, for colorings using exactly $M$ colors we get

$$B_M = \frac{M!}{4}  
\left({49\brace M} + {25\brace M} + 2 {13\brace M}\right).$$

Hence we obtain with exactly three colors

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
59824831885653715102950.}$$